# Set rosparam for ~ handle

Tags: rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
i'm using code

```
ros::NodeHandle ph("~");
ph.param("scale_angular", a_scale, a_scale);
ph.param("scale_linear", l_scale, l_scale);
```

How could i set scale_angular from console via rosparam utility?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66691/set-rosparam-for-%7E-handle/) by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 471 on 2013-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosparam set NODE_NAME/scale_angular VALUE`

or when starting you node pass `_scale_angular:=VALUE`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2013-07-05**:
Thanks !!!